# Are there any differences between using `forRoot` or `register` when creating a Dynamic Module in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I am new to NestJS and I would like to create a Dynamic Module for the injection of a metrics reporter provider. The documentation for NestJS says the following about Dynamic Modules:

> ...by convention we should call it either `forRoot()` or `register()` [when creating a Dynamic Module]

Unfortunately, the documentation gives no clear guidance as to when you should implement `register` or `forRoot` or what the expectations in the implementation of the two functions should be. This leads me to believe that I could call the function `cheeseburger` and as long as it returns a `DynamicModule`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I like to do is use `forRoot`/`forRootAsync` for initial module configurations. From there if I need to be able to pass in new options for some services i like to use `forFeature`. This helps me keep in mind that the DyanmicModule is configured in the root of my application (usually `AppModule`) and can be used elsewhere in the application, either via `forFeature()` or by importing the expected module. Otherwise, you are absolutely right, you could call it `cheeseburger` and it would be just fine. No differences other than what others using the package might be expecting

Comment: Thanks Jay. This explanation seems reasonable.

Comment: @Jay do you by chance have an example somewhere demonstrating this pattern?